# How to sort result by multiplying some values in Spring?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, sorting

So, I have the model Book, that has physical size: height, width and length. My repository method look like:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT b FROM Book b ORDER BY b.bookHeight * b.bookWidth * b.bookLength")
List<Book> getAllBooksOrderedByVolumePaginated(PageRequest request);
```

I want to create endpoint with query parameter `sortOrder` where I will be able to put `asc` or `desc` sorting order.

Have the next code on service layer:

```
private Sort.Direction resolveDirection(String order) {
    Sort.Direction orderType = null;

    if (order.equals("desc"))
        orderType = Sort.Direction.DESC;
    else if (order.equals("asc"))
        orderType = Sort.Direction.ASC;

    return orderType;
}

public List<BookDto> findAllBooksSortedByVolume(int page, int size, String order) {
    Sort.Direction orderType = resolveDirection(order);
    List<Book> books = bookRepository.getAllBooksOrderedByVolumePaginated(
            PageRequest.of(page - 1, size, Sort.by(orderType)));

    return mapToDto(books);
}
```

And I get the exception to specify sort parameter:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one property must be given!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:118)
    at org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.by(Sort.java:165)
    at ua.com.epam.service.BookService.findAllBooksSortedByVolume(BookService.java:106)
    at ua.com.epam.controller.BookController.getAllBooksSortedInSomeDimension(BookController.java:156)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: How is `resolveDirection(order)` implemented?

Comment: @Sebastian, I edit question body

Comment: Your `Sort.Direction` (orderType) is null, change your `resolveDirection` to return `ASC` by default.

Comment: @Shadov, No! It check on controllers, and if sort order is not desc or asc, API will throw an specified exception for this

Comment: If specifying an expression in the order by clause is a problem then _may be_ you can add the expression in the select clause and order by it `SELECT b, b.bookHeight * b.bookWidth * b.bookLength AS x_volume FROM Book b ORDER BY x_volume`

Comment: @SalmanA, good idea, but I think it will be not posible without specifing this in model. So I must specify sort by virtual parameter that not exists in original model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Hibernate as JPA provider then you can use `@Formula` to declare a "virtual column".

```
@Entity
class Book {
    ...
    @Formula("bookHeight * bookWidth * bookLength")
    private long volume;

    // Just in case you want to access volume in java code.
    // If you don't want then remove `getVolume` from class
    @Transient
    public long getVolume() { 
        return volume;
    }
    ...
}
```

And sort by this column

```
PageRequest.of(page - 1, size, Sort.by(orderType, "volume"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify at least one property to sort by. You specified the direction but sorts by needs a property too. Check the implementation of `Sort.by`:

```
public static Sort by(Direction direction, String... properties) {
    Assert.notNull(direction, "Direction must not be null!");
    Assert.notNull(properties, "Properties must not be null!");
    Assert.isTrue(properties.length > 0, "At least one property must be given!");

    return Sort.by(Arrays.stream(properties)//
            .map(it -> new Order(direction, it))//
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know it. But the property to sort by is b.bookHeight * b.bookWidth * b.bookLength. How can I specify it??

Comment: You need to tell him which column you want to sort by. I do not think you can pass the calculated value.